# Numpy dot product for group of rows

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to calculate a dot product between two matrices, for each couple of rows. 
I have matrix `D` with `(u x 2)` dimensions and matrix R with `(u*2 x c)` dimensions.
Below an example:

```
D = np.array([[0.02747092, 0.11233295],
              [0.02747092, 0.07295284],
              [0.01245856, 0.19935923],
              [0.01245856, 0.13520913],
              [0.11233295, 0.07295284]])

R = np.array([[-3.        ,  0.        ,  1.        , -1.        ],
              [-1.25      ,  0.75      ,  1.75      , -1.25      ],
              [-2.33333333, -0.33333333,  1.66666667, -1.33333333],
              [-1.25      ,  0.75      ,  1.75      , -1.25      ],
              [ 0.        , -2.        ,  2.        , -4.        ],
              [-1.25      ,  0.75      ,  1.75      , -1.25      ],
              [ 0.66666667, -3.33333333,  2.66666667, -4.33333333],
              [-1.25      ,  0.75      ,  1.75      , -1.25      ],
              [-2.33333333, -0.33333333,  1.66666667, -1.33333333],
              [-3.        ,  0.        ,  1.        , -1.        ]])
```

The result should be matrix M with dimensions `(u x c)` as follows (example of first row):

```
M = np.array([[-0.2185,  0.0825,  0.2195, -0.1645],
              [...]])
```

Which is result of `dot` product between the first row of `D` and first two rows of matrix `R` as such:

```
D_ = np.array([[0.027, 0.11]])
R_ = np.array([[-3.,  0.,  1., -1.],
               [-1.25, 0.75, 1.75, -1.25]])

D_.dot(R_)
```

I tried various ways of `np.tensordot` after reshaping the `D` matrix into tensor, but without any luck. I am looking for vectorized solution and to avoid loops (which is my current solution, quite slow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reshape `R` to 3D and use `np.einsum` -

```
np.einsum('ijk,ij->ik',R.reshape(len(D),2,-1),D)
```